# Group by out vertices in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

i have this structure:

Groups -> Fields -> Values

and a command `g.V().hasLabel('groups').out('fields').out('values')`

how can I group these values by fields and by 'groups' vertices?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [answered on the Gremlin Users list by Daniel Kuppitz](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/NJ9iCYtP8yg):

> ```
> g.V().hasLabel("groups").
>   group().
>     by().
>     by(out("fields").
>          group().
>            by().
>            by(out("values").fold()))
> ```